# How is "crumby" different from "dirty" (or similar words)?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I'm working on a translation of *The catcher in the Rye* and Holden seems to prefer the word **crumby** to other adjectives to describe, well, dirty stuff:

> That isn’t too far from this crumby place, and he comes over and visits me practically every week end.
>
> "I don’t feel like walking on your crumby nails in my bare feet tonight."
>
> "He started shaving himself all over again. He always shaved himself twice, to look gorgeous. With his crumby old razor."

He also uses **dirty** quite often:

> His teeth were always mossy-looking, and his ears were always dirty as hell, but he was always cleaning his fingernails.
>
> He got up off me, and I got up, too. My chest hurt like hell from his dirty knees. “You’re a dirty stupid sonuvabitch of a moron,” I told him.

As a non-native English speaker, looking at dictionaries and context seems to indicate they are very close in meaning. But well, there are never *really* synonyms, are there? How do they differ?

Comment: Crumby (crummy) can also mean “low quality or cheap”

Comment: "Crumby" is different from "crummy".  "Crumby" *can* mean "like crumbs" or "covered with crumbs" or "flaking crumbs".  "Crummy" just means "crummy".

Comment: @HotLicks - At least one dictionary says: *crumby* : variant spelling of *crummy*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Crumby* - along with *lousy*, *phony*, and so on - are examples of Holden Caulfield's distinctive vernacular (sometimes referred to as *Holdenese*).

*Crumby* as a synonym for *inferior* or *shoddy* [goes back to the 19th century](https://www.etymonline.com/word/crummy), and this is the sense in which Salinger uses it in Holden's narrative, which is casual in tone and peppered with such slang terms.

*Dirty* in the first two examples you give has its primary meaning as an adjective: *unclean*. The last, however, (*"dirty stupid sonuvabitch of a moron*") is similar in tone to the adverb usage seen in British English, and usually followed by *great*, as in *You dirty great idiot!*